# Why are spells considered an attack for shield spell but not extra attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

Sifting through the threads I can't make heads or tails of it. From my understanding the *shield* spell can somehow trigger from a spell that uses an attack roll (the spell being considered an "attack" in this circumstance) yet for things like extra attack, spells are not considered an "attack." Personally I would argue that *shield* spell can't trigger from a spell attack but instead only from a melee or ranged weapon attack and the obvious *magic missile* as well.

Comment: Relevant: [What does upper-case-A-Attack action vs. lower-case-a-attack mean?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781)

Comment: Worth noting: [magic missile is not an attack](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/10/11/is-magic-missile-an-attack-that-hits-without-an-attack-roll/) even though shield works on it.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96656/can-i-use-shield-spell-to-protect-me-from-other-attacks-than-just-physicals-and

Answer (score 24):

The actions Attack and Cast a Spell are separate action options. You either use one or the other. Extra Attack requires you to use the Attack action:

> Beginning at 5th leveI, you can attack twice, instead of once,
>   whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. (PHB 72)

Thus you cannot cast two spells with Extra Attack. However, both are capable of launching an attack (note the lowercase 'a'), which is anything that requires an attack roll. The *shield* spell can be used against any kind of attack, not just ones launched with the Attack action, as it states no such requirement.

Comment: Related: [lowercase-a-attack vs. uppercase-A-Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105781/23970)

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking there should be an errata to clarify like "or spell attack"  or even a small section in the phb that distinguishes Attack from attack but it makes sense to me. Thank you very much!